# OBS - black screen while capturing display

Tags: windows, obs

I have a problem with OBS. I'd like to make tutorials how to do programming, teach people basics & show them, for example, how to write neural network in Java (without any ML libraries) but in order to do so, it would be great to show them my presentation about it and other windows, so recording full screen is needed (I know I could keep switching windows but it's faster and easier to display full screen). When I added the source "capture screen" the captured screen is black but audio works. I've tried to solve this problem and I went through many tutorials (like 15 or smth) and nothing has helped. I've also added a new thread in OBS Official Forum but nobody has responded. My OBS version is 25.0.4. Here is what I've tried:
- I ran the program as an administrator
- I have reinstalled it (with deleting all files and settings ~ no leftovers)
- In Nvidia Control Panel in 3D Settings I've selected OBS Studio and changed graphic processor to an integrated graphic (also tried dedicated graphic and global choice - nothing worked)
- In GForce Experience I disabled sharing
- Couple times I've restarted the computer and OBS (after any change I've done)
- I ran the OBS in compatibility mode with Windows 8 (and I've tried Windows build-in troubleshooting option)
- I ran OBS with an integrated graphic from a desktop

What I've discovered is the capturing specific window works perfectly, the problem occurs only with capturing full screen.
I have no idea what to do, please help me.

Here is what I see:

[It looks like OBS just "can't see" screen, I use only one screen by the way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T35fE.jpg)

[Black screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mAPhf.jpg)

[though single-window capturing works perfectly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/niIwS.jpg)

[5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pj3N6.jpg)

[OBS Settings vol.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QatE2.jpg)

[OBS Settings vol.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/enqM9.jpg)

Logs:

https://obsproject.com/logs/NMexpZp-b4nXDxLl

Specifications of my computer:
I use a laptop - MSI GF 63 8RC
- Intell Core i5 8300H
- GForce GTX 1050 (actualizations are installed) 4GB VRAM
- Windows 10 Home, 64bit (updated to version 1909)
- 16GB RAM
- FHD Screen (1920x1080)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to change the Graphic for this app to integrated graphic

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in the virtual machine And I solved it this way go to virtual machine setting
in display section uncheck Accelerate 3D graphics
The problem was solved and the recording was done correctly.